# OnNewMessageCompose working in office 365 but not in live.com or desktop version

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a simple plugin that add lines to composed email body, it works perfect with Office 365 web version but didn't work in outlook desktop or with my live.com with my hotmail account,

```
<DesktopFormFactor>
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
          <LaunchEvents>
            <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="checkSignature" />
          </LaunchEvents>
          <SourceLocation resid="https://localhost:3000/autorunshared.js" />
      </ExtensionPoint>
</DesktopFormFactor>
```

and here the js,

```
function checkSignature(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {
   console.log('--------------------checkSignature ',event);
}
```

Comment: From the snippet of the manifest XML in your post, is the resid actually the full path to the hosted JS file? If so, it shouldn't be. The resid should be an ID that matches that of a Runtime element in your add-in, as well as a URL in the Resources section of your add-in.

Comment: yes, but it works in outlook web for me and in desktop version it didn't fire at all

Comment: Using the full URL as the resid of the SourceLocation will not work in both the Desktop Outlook app and the Outlook web app. The resid value should be a unique identifier that points to a URL resource in the Resources section of the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `resid` attribute of the `SourceLocation` element should be an ID, instead of the full URL path. See the code snippet below:

```
<!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
<Runtimes>
    <!--
    HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
    This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI preview.
    -->
    <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
        <!--
        JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook Desktop.
        -->
        <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
    </Runtime>
</Runtimes>
....
....
....
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
    <LaunchEvents>
        <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="checkSignature" />
    </LaunchEvents>
    <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url" />
</ExtensionPoint>
....
....
....
<bt:Urls>
    <!-- Entry needed for Outlook on the Web / new Mac UI preview. -->
    <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/autorun.html" />
    <!-- Entry needed for Outlook Desktop. -->
    <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/autorunshared.js" />
</bt:Urls>
```

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

The behavior your seeing, where Outlook on the web is somehow working when you use a full URL as the value of the `SourceLocation` sounds like a potential bug. I will pass it along to the Outlook Web team.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work with Exchange accounts only. Typically add-ins are installed per-mailbox in the desktop versions of Outlook.

If you need to support multiple accounts in Outlook desktop with IMAP or  other non-exchange accounts you may consider creating a COM add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for more information.